Does Kernel Driver backports from the later version to the older version still works?
I am looking about Kernel Driver Backports.
https://developer-archives.toradex.com/knowledge-base/kernel-backports-integration/
There is a comment in the link saying backports allows the use of drivers from a newer kernel version on an older kernel version.
I think this backports is for the case bring the driver from the later version such as v4.19 to the current version such as 4.9.
But in other case such as I want to use the specific driver from the 4.9 to the running Kernel version 4.19, how this backports working?

"But in other case such as I want to use the specific driver from the 4.9 to the running Kernel version 4.19 ..." - Then that is a case of forward-porting.

Backporting is not a magic one-click thing. It means for a developer to read the new code, understand what it does, and then do the same with the old software (Linux kernel in this case) version. Sometimes the new code would need very few, if any, changes. Sometimes this would need extensive rewriting of the code. Other times, it would simply be infeasible, because you’d effectively rebuild the entire software version you are attempting to port from.
Every single line of code must be transferred and maybe adapted manually. If you are not a developer, you cannot do it.
The page you link to refers to work done by developers.
